# How to change execution context in jQuery without invoking the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a lover of MooTools, and get used to bind the callback functions, for example:

```
element.addEvent('click', callback.bind(this));
```

Assume *this* is the current execution context. This statement means that, I'm binding the execution context of *this* to the function *callback*. Also, as far as I know, certain browsers (e.g., Chrome) have added bind() into their JavaScript engines.

Now my job needs me to switch to using jQuery. Clearly, the bind() has a different meaning in jQuery, which is close to addEvent() in MooTools. I could not figure out a way to change the execution context. I had to do the following:

```
var that = this;
element.click(function () {
    callback.apply(that); // Have to invoke it, and also with extra function wrapper
});
```

But I wanted to do something like:

```
element.click(callback.*bind*(this));
```

Any jQuery guru has ideas?

Comment: You could add to `Function.prototype` a function that wraps the function in another that does the `apply` call, I imagine. I 'm under the impression that this is not considered good practice in JS though.

Comment: You already have the answer... apply or call your function with THAT

Comment: Mohsen, please see my title. I dont want to invoke the function. I just wanted to pass a copy of the callback with a different context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See **[jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)**.

`element.click($.proxy(callback, this));`

Comment: This is not from base library of library, is it? I saw this, but it looked like a plugin.

Comment: Yes, it was added to jQuery core in jQuery v1.4.